# spyder não consegue ler porta serial

Tags: python, linux, serial, porta-serial

Criei o seguinte programa teste:

```
import serial
porta = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
baud_rate = 9600


try:

       Obj_porta = serial.Serial(porta, baud_rate)
       valor = Obj_porta.read()
       print valor
       Obj_porta.close()
except serial.SerialException:
       print"ERRO: Verifique se ha algum dispositivo conectado na porta!"
```

Ele apresenta a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
 runfile('/home/joannis/.spyder2/.temp.py', wdir=r'/home/joannis/.spyder2')
ERRO: Verifique se ha algum dispositivo conectado na porta!
```

Sempre cai no except, como se realmente não tivesse nada na porta. 
Quando tiro o try/except, ele diz que não tem acesso. (permissão negada)

```
runfile('/home/joannis/.spyder2/.temp.py', wdir=r'/home/joannis/.spyder2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/joannis/.spyder2/.temp.py", line 20, in <module>
    Obj_porta = serial.Serial(porta, baud_rate)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 261, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 278, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
```

Quando faço a leitura manualmente pelo terminal funciona perfeitamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então - o problema é justamente que você não tem permissão no dispositivo serial.

Você reparou que todos os comandos que você digita de teste você digita "sudo" antes - ou seja, os aplicativos acessam a porta serial como o usuário root.

Se você chamar a sua aplicação com sudo - `suddo python meuprog.py` vai ver que também funciona. Pela sua saída você está executando o programa direto de dentro de uma IDE - e ela, obviamente, não vai deixar você colocar um "sudo" na frente. Um arquivo `.py` no disco é um programa como qualquer outro. Certifique-se de que 
a IDE está ajudando e não deixe-a ficar no seu caminho.

À parte de executar o programa com sudo, a solução mais permanente é  mudar as permissões da sua porta serial: em algumas distribuições, simplesmente fazer  `chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0` pode ser o suficiente.

Comment: n tem como configurar a IDE para ela acessar como root?

Comment: a propósito o chmod 666 /devttyUSB0 funcionou. dei um --help entendi o comando, só não entendi o porque do 666 mas todo caso muito obrigado!

Comment: O comando chmod é um dos poucos lugares onde se usa números em Octal.  Cada dígito é um número de 0 até 7, que em binário é representado por 3 bits ; O primeiro dígito controla as permissões do dono do arquivo (no caso, o dono é o "root"), o segundo digito controa as permissões para quem estiver no mesmo grupo (de usuários) que o arquivo, e o terceiro dígito controla as permissões de todos os usuários do sistema. Em cada um dos três dígitos, o primeiro bit controla acesso a leitura, o segundo a escrita e o terceiro a execução. Assim, "666" diz quer todos podem ler e escrever no arquivo.

Comment: entendi, obrigado!